# JavaFX Clock widget throws Exceptions randomly

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, time-format

I have written a little Clock Widget extending the `Text` class of JavaFX. To update the Time I am using a `Task` that basically sets the text to the current System Time. When I run this application in Eclipse it sometimes throws a `NullpointerException` in the line I call `stage.show()`.

This is what my widgets sourcecode looks like:

```
package clock;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CurrentClockText extends Text {
    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public static final int HOUR = 1;
    public static final int HOUR_MINUTE = 2;
    public static final int HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND = 3;
    public static final int HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND_MILLISECOND = 4;

    private final long updateInterval;

    private final Task<Void> updater = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                String nowTextual = formatter.format(now);
                setText(nowTextual);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(updateInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public CurrentClockText() {
        this(HOUR_MINUTE);
    }

    public CurrentClockText(final int detailLevel) {
        String timeFormat = "";
        switch (detailLevel) {
        case HOUR:
            timeFormat = "HH";
            updateInterval = 60000;
            break;
        case HOUR_MINUTE:
            timeFormat = "HH:mm";
            updateInterval = 15000;
            break;
        case HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND:
            timeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
            updateInterval = 500;
            break;
        case HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND_MILLISECOND:
            updateInterval = 1;
            timeFormat = "HH:mm:ss.S";
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unknown detail level for Clock: " + detailLevel);
        }

        setFont(new Font("Verdana", 28));

        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat);
        Thread updaterThread = new Thread(updater, "CurrentClockText.updaterThread");
        updaterThread.setDaemon(true);
        updaterThread.start();
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
package clock;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Boot extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        CurrentClockText clock = new CurrentClockText(4);
        pane.setCenter(clock);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boot.launch(args);
    }

}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/14845382.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeLayoutBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node$12.computeBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLayoutBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.prefWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.minWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.getAreaWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.computePrefWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.getPreferredWidth(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.resizeRootToPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at clock.Boot.start(Boot.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/19600960.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/18503843.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/27167109.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2180324.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/3326003.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application clock.Boot
```

As I said this Exception only occurs in some runs and not always. It happens mostly when I change the formatting pattern of `detailLevel = 4` but remains for another run after changing it back again. I am guessing this might actually have something to do with Eclipse but I can't debug the code either because the Exception gets thrown in the `stage.show` call which I absolutely do not understand. What's the cause of this random Exception and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html: [...] you must ensure that you use `Platform.runLater` so that any modifications of the scene graph occur on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: @AndreasFester that actually seems to have fixed the problem. Can you post that as an answer so that I can mark this as done? Thanks! I call `setText`like this now: `Platform.runLater(() -> setText(nowTextual));`. However this seems to have broken the preferred width of the Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaFX, as in most other GUI toolkits, there is one specific thread which handles all UI related operations. An application must not update the UI outside of this thread. If the UI needs to be updated from another thread, there are usually APIs available which ensure that code is executed in the context of the UI thread. In case of JavaFX, see the [Concurrency in JavaFX Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm%20for%20more%20information.) for more information.

In your case, the simplest solution would be to make sure that your `setText()` call is executed on the JavaFX application thread, not on the thread associated with your `Task`:

```
...
Platform.runLater(() -> setText(nowTextual));
...
```

There are also other APIs available in JavaFX to do animations, which can be used to call a handler method at specific time intervals - that would remove the `Thread.sleep()` call from your loop. See [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) for more information.